# Unable to add UI elements in hierarchy to prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a player prefab that is spawned when the game starts via Network Manager, the player prefab has a script(Player Health) attached to it which takes 2 UI element as input(DamageImage, HealthSlider) present in the hierarchy.The problem i face is that I cant add these inputs in the prefab which results in **Object reference not set to an instance of an object** error.

Tried to add them by placing the prefab in hierarchy and then saving it but it did not help.

Comment: That doesn't have to do with the hierarchy but the fact that the UI elements are being referenced as objects when they are not instantiated as an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the UI elements aren't in the prefab itself or in one of its children then you will lose the reference once you make the prefab.

What you can do is set the tag of those elements to something like "DamageImage" and "HealthSlider" and then in the Awake() function of a your PlayerHealth script attached to your prefab do this:

```
void Awake(){
  DamageImage = GameObject.FindWithTag("DamageImage").GetComponent<Image>();
  HealthSlider = GameObject.FindWithTag("HealthSlider").GetComponent<Slider>();
}
```